# How to remove lagging in RecyclerView showing captured images from the camera?

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, picasso

I am showing images captured from camera on cards using `RecyclerView`. I don't know why the app lags whenever I scroll down the screen. I am also using Picasso to load images async. Please help. Below is the code :

**Check the `onBindViewHolder` function**

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DiaryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DiaryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List <DiaryInfo> mItems;

public DiaryAdapter() {
    super();
    mItems = new ArrayList <DiaryInfo> ();
    mItems = MainActivity.diaryinfo;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.content_main, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    DiaryInfo info = mItems.get(i);
    viewHolder.date.setText(info.getDate());
    viewHolder.desc.setText(Html.fromHtml((info.getDesc()).replaceAll("''","\"")));

    String data = info.getThumbnail();

    String path=""; // Final path of the thumbnail

    final SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = (MainActivity.mContext).openOrCreateDatabase("remember", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    // While changing database information here change at Itemadd's done button listener also!
    mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS memories_pics(id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, path VARCHAR)");

    Cursor cursor = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM memories_pics WHERE id=\'" + data + "\' LIMIT 1", null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            path = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex("path"));
            cursor.moveToNext();
            break;
        }
    }
    cursor.close();

    //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(path.split("=")[0]));
    //viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageURI(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path.split("=")[0])));
    File file = new File(String.valueOf(path.split("=")[0]));
    Picasso.with(MainActivity.mContext).load(file).into(viewHolder.imgThumbnail);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

public Object getItem(int pos) { return mItems.get(pos); }

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imgThumbnail;
    public TextView date, desc;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imgThumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        date = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        desc = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.mContext).load(file).fit().centerCrop().into(viewHolder.imgThumbnail);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing 2 database operations at each `onBindViewHolder`. I think you should keep the `onBindViewHolder` as simple as possible. Just create that table if it not exists at the startup of your app and load all image **paths** (not the images) at the creation of your adapter (async). If there are alot of images maybe load some for a quick display and all others in the background.

And then ensure that you have

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>` in your `AppManifest.xml`set.